# Concatenate and dropping leading zeros

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

Column A was formatted using Custom to include leading zeros.
Colum B was concat to include format for use in SQL. There are over 11,000 lines in Column A.

[image: image capturing data and concat]

Need to figure out how to keep leading zeros in column B and still have format for sql

Comment: Instead of `A1` use `TEXT(A1,"000000000000")`

Comment: BTW If you have it: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",,"'"&TEXT(A1:A10,"000000000000")&"'")` will join them all together.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the followings:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=BASE(A1:A4,10,MAX(LEN(A1:A4)))
```

---

Or could use `TEXT()` + `REPT()` function combo:

```
=LET(a,A1:A4,TEXT(a,REPT("0",MAX(LEN(a)))))
```

---

<sup>Note that the use of `MAX()` & `LEN()` only because if the values in `Column A` has varying length of characters.</sup>

---

If the length of characters are not varying and remains same for the whole range could simplify it as :

[image]

---

```
=RIGHT(REPT(0,11)&A1:A4,11)
```

---

```
=BASE(A1:A4,10,11)
```

---

```
=LET(a,A1:A4,TEXT(a,REPT("0",LEN(a))))
```

---

Or as mentioned in comments by **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir if you want to combine all into one then using `ARRAYTOTEXT()` + `TOCOL()`

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT("'"&TOCOL(A:A,1)&"'")
```

---

If one don't have access to `ARRAYTOTEXT()` then:

```
=LET(_a,FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),TEXTJOIN(", ",,TEXT(_a,REPT("0",LEN(_a)))))
```

---